# How to change dynamically function overload?

Tags: c#, wsdl

I want to create dynamic WSDL, for example:

I have this method:

```
public void test(string test1);
```

I want to add, dynamically, more variables to this method in running, than to get different WSDL.

I want to convert this method to this in running:

```
public void test(string test1,string test3);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't how will achieve it but you can always pass delegate/ action as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Swift but not C#